# when select category not show subcategory

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is controller file code

```
 public function call_pageAjax($id)
{
  $subcat = DB::table("sub_categories")->where("cat_id",$id)->pluck("sub_cat_nm","id");
  return json_encode($subcat);
//  return view('purchase.supplier.add_supplier',compact('subcat'));
}
```

This is javascript file

```js
          <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function() {
                $('select[name="category"]').on('change', function() {
                    var catID = $(this).val();
                    if(catId) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/purchase/supplier/add_supplier/ajax/'+ catID,
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success:function(data) {

                                
                                $('select[name="subcategory"]').empty();
                                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                                    $('select[name="subcategory"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                                    console.log(data);
                                });


                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        $('select[name="subcategory"]').empty();
                    }
                });
            }); 
          
        </script>
```

```html
This is view file.

 <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" style="text-align-last: right;">Category Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
                                <option value=" ">----select Category----</option>
                                @foreach ($category as $key => $value)
                                    <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>

                        </div>
                    </div>              
                    
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" style="text-align-last: right;">Sub Category Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                           <select class="form-control" id="subcategory" name="subcategory">
                            
                           </select> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

i am trying to get subcategory when i click category on a page but not display subcategory. Subcategory is display in API but isn't show in the page...

[image]

Comment: Is there any errors in the console?

Comment: no any error in console

Comment: Can you post the result of the ```console.log(data) ```

Comment: Can you see the ajax request in the network tab of your developer tools?

Comment: no i can't see anything

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
//...
success: function(data){

     //Log the data to the console so that
     //you can get a better view of what the script is returning.
     console.log(data);
     $('#subcategory').empty();
     $.each(data, function(key, value){
           //Use the Option() constructor to create a new HTMLOptionElement.
           var option = new Option(key, value);
           //Convert the HTMLOptionElement into a JQuery object that can be used with the append method.
           $(option).html(value);
           //Append the option to our Select element.
           $('#subcategory').append(option);
     });

}
```

Comment: Probably your returned data from controller is empty

Comment: I mean what did you get when you console.log(data) success: function(data){} ?

Comment: @Shifu you could join me here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206269/when-select-category-not-show-subcategory for 1 to 1 support

Comment: i have not enough 20 reputation..can you give me the point of question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206270/discussion-between-shifu-and-foued-moussi).